# antlr match different bracketed parts

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have the following language to define, and apparently ANTLR is not giving away its secrets to easy.

```
ui { 
  screen X {
    input()
    checkbox()
  }
}
model {
 // any text
 // even {}

}
```

I would define

```
ui: UI OBR (screen)* CBR;

screen: ....

model : MODEL modelBody;

modelBody: BRACKETED_TEXT;

OBR: '{';
CBR: '}';
...
TEXT : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'| '_' | '-' )+ ;
BRACKETED_TEXT : OBR ( ~(OBR|CBR ) | BRACKETED_TEXT )*  CBR;
```

The problem is that it throws a `MismatchedTokenException` when hitting the `ui {` part. If I remove the BRACKETED_TEXT token all goes well, so I'm figuring it must be the fact that it cannot know whether it can match an OBR or a BRACKETED_TEXT when parsing `ui {`.

This is fine but how can I have structured AST for `ui {...}` and free text for the `model {..}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer is like this :

```
ui: UI OBR (screen)* CBR;

screen: ....

model : MODEL modelBody;

modelBody: genericBlock; // no more BRACKETED_TEXT

genericBlock
 : OBR
  ( TEXT
  | QUOTED_TEXT
  | OPAR
  | CPAR
  | genericBlock
)*
CBR
 ;

OBR: '{';
CBR: '}';
OPAR: '(';// this was part of the initial grammar file, but left out
CPAR: ')';// same here
...
TEXT : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'| '_' | '-' )+ ;
```

Question still remains, and I hope someone can clear it. Why do I have to declare all the tokens which will not be present in the generic block ? If lexer encounters a declared TOKEN inside the `genericBlock`, he fails. Why is that I specifically told it to match anything else other than `OBR` and `CBR`.